# cleditor problem with jquery ui effect()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, animation, effects, cleditor

I'm using cleditor on one of my sites and I have run into a problem. When I use effect to animate some divs cleditor's wysiwyg editor stops working. The editor itself shows but I cant type anything into it. I can view/edit the source on the editor just fine.

Code I use to toggle between divs:

```
function emailwizardplace(pold, pnew) {
    $("#wizard-" + pold).hide();
    $("#wizard-" + pnew).effect('slide');
    //$("#wizard-" + pnew).show(); <= This works without problems
}
```

Code for calling cleditor:

```
$("#tmessage").cleditor({
    width: 680,
    height: 400
});
```

As always any help is appreciated.

Comment: it's almost impossible to help without seeing the actual page or at least some html or demo page. only thing i could think of is, that some element overlays the editor area or something

Comment: on which browser do you have the problem? it seems to work fine on chrome.

Comment: I ended up changing it to just fade. I still would prefer it to slide though.

Comment: I have replicated the problem at https://app.emailsmsmarketing.com/cleditor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with the interaction between CLEditor and jQuery.UI. Have you tried this?

```
$("#tmessage").cleditor()[0].disable(false).refresh();
```

There's quite a bit of discussion in google groups on this problem. Here's one link that outlines the problem and what others have done.  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/cleditor/6W36CyPsaVU

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
function emailwizardplace(pold, pnew) {
    $("#wizard-" + pold).hide();
    $("#wizard-" + pnew).effect('slide');
    $("#wizard-" + pnew).show('slide',function(){
        $("#tmessage").cleditor({
            width: 680,
            height: 400
        });
    });
};
```

You have to place the call for the cleditor inside the .show()