# cleditor comes up disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cleditor

I am using "CLEditor WYSIWYG HTML Editor v1.4.5"

When I open the window containing the TextArea element I'm using with clEditor, the Editor comes up disabled and it appears that the TextArea element is invisible.  I have text in the TextArea element but the text is invisible.

If I right click on the body of the TextArea and select "Inspect Element", the debugger window opens and the Editor becomes enabled and the TextArea becomes visible. Then I close the debugger window and everything appears to be functioning correctly.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="maintBody">
     <textarea id="woEditor" name="woEditor">This is the test data... is this editable?</textarea>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#woEditor").cleditor( {height: "400"});
```

**No CSS**

If I comment out the Javascript .cleditor() call, then the TextArea element appears and functions correctly. So there is definately some setting in the editor initialization that is setting this state.

You can access this page at:  http://test.nds.link then click on the "Props" Tab in the left column

Does anyone know what would cause the clEditor to come up in a disabled state, making the TextArea element invisible?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error while I using CLEditor inside a DIV which was toggled via jQuery.

The animation-Parameter cause the error! After I removed it, it works like a charm!

**wrong way:**

```
$("#cT_new_form").toggle("slide",700);
```

**right way:**

```
$("#cT_new_form").toggle(700);
```

So don't use "slide" as animation or CLEditor won't focus after slide!!!

Answer (score 0):

The following fixed this issue for me without having to remove the effects:
[cleditor problem with jquery ui effect()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538715/cleditor-problem-with-jquery-ui-effect)